# Libtorch C++ - no matching member function for call to 'size' for InterpolateFuncOptions

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

Using Libtorch 1.6.0 in C++, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'size'
```

My line is the following:

```
image = F::interpolate(image, F::InterpolateFuncOptions().size({target_height, target_width}).mode(torch::kNearest));
```

But in the documentation it seems correct... Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PyTorch version? And did you try `F::InterpolateFuncOptions().size(std::vector<int64_t>{target_height, target_width})`?

Comment: 1.6.0 and indeed, it does work. Thanks a lot for that :)

Comment: added an answer with a little bit of context for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap it with `std::vector` like this:

```
image = F::interpolate(image, 
        F::InterpolateFuncOptions()
        .size(std::vector<>{target_height, target_width})
        .mode(torch::kNearest));
```

Reason for this is `size` has no overloaded call for [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) that you were trying to use (see `size` docs [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/structtorch_1_1nn_1_1functional_1_1_interpolate_func_options.html#_CPPv4N5torch2nn10functional22InterpolateFuncOptions4sizeERKN3c108optionalINSt6vectorI7int64_tEEEE)).